# Show #answers after pressing "new questions with activity" button

Tags: feature-request

On SO I am always browsing [C#] or [TDD] questions. I have different app-tabs in firefox that list the newest questions for a specific topic so that I can easily see if there is something of interest for me.

when a new questions arises, I get a uber cool "new question with activity" button. When I press it, I get x new questions in my list. But, the slightly disappointing part is that it does not show if there already (accepted) answers to those questions. (In general I don't read questions that have 5 answers in the first minute, I don't have a lot to add in those cases).

Thus, I always find myself pressing F5 to reload the page, because then the #answers **are** shown for the questions.

Is this deliberate? The current implementation of the *new questions with activity* feature is not really useful to me.

Comment: I never hit reload in my browser if the notification rises. If I do I don't get to see the most current questions for some reason. I always hit the notification. Maybe related...

Comment: Hmm, that I don't recognize. If I hit the button and press F5 the list remains the same, just the numbers appear and whether or not the question has an accepted answer.

Comment: It occurred to me that I don't actually click on that new questions banner. I use it as a signal to press F5, and I always have... Anyway, I agree, number of answers on a brand new question can be a useful metric and should be included if possible, but I guess there's a question of *when* the data is loaded -- it might not work as fast to delay the load until the banner is clicked.